# Why Does Ubuntu 12.04 logout as soon as I login?

Tags: 12.04, login

So I was working on ubuntu and I had to go away for about 5 mins and closed my chromebook's screen, when I came back and opened the screen I found out it shut down by itself. So turned it back on and tried to login into ubuntu and the screen went black which means I'm logging in but it comes back to the screen of logging out

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 then log in from there, do you get any errors? You might get an error about a missing $HOME or home directory, which could be stopping you from logging in.